# Normal life with heavy weights?

Tags: sleep, exercise, weight, muscle, stress

On an animated TV show (dragon ball Z) characters would have clothes which seamed 3 times their own weight. Gradually building up could one be able to carry evenly across there body 3 times there weight and feel normal? What would be the upside and downsides?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you build this up gradually, then you're more likely to succeed, although it may still be above the limit that your body can tolerate in the long term. In general, exercise stresses the body, but the body then responds to that by making itself stronger not just to meet the extra demand but to actually exceed this (provided the exercise routine isn't too strenuous). If you do bodyweight exercises like [these](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=POdzasJklxw) with weighted clothing then it is actually possible that with the extra weight you'll actually feel lighter than you felt before you started wearing weighted clothing due to increased muscle mass, at least up to some maximum weight. At some point, it will become too much for your body to sustain.